# Accessing outer class variable in inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

In inner classes, variables of outer class are accessible, but local variables of a method are not. I understood the part about local variables of a method not being accessible but I want to know why outer class variables are accessible?

My understanding is that as an inner class binds with the outer class, so as long as the parent is available, the child can access its parent variables. Am I correct?

Comment: Static inner class or non-static?

Comment: @DuncanJones: inner classes are always non-static. Have a look at here.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @VishalK Thanks, I've been mistakenly calling nested classes *inner classes* for years. Whoops!

Comment: I think this post is later than op's time when s/he asked, but it is a good reference https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/nested-inner-class

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Assuming your outer class is called `Outer`, from the scope of the inner class(non-static), `Outer.this.foo` to get at the field.

For example,

```
Outer.this.foo=new ArrayList<>();
```

where Outer is the name of the class and `foo` identifies the field.

You can also grab it directly as `foo=new Baz()` but it'll pick the inner field if there's a naming conflict due to shadowing.

if it's a static inner class, you need an explicit instance:

```
outerInstance.foo=new ArrayList<>();
```

or if the field to access is static, access it as usual with:

```
Outer.staticFoo=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for reply,Here my question is if inner class and outer class uses the variable at a time there might be a chance of concurrent issues.But, the inner classes uses variable as how two methods of a class use.so, we should need to use synchhronization to handle this with inner class.

Comment: @user5 No, not beyond any synchronization you would need to do in any other case. Inner and outer classes do not cause new threads to be created.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** Outer class variables in java are accessible because of lexical scope.

**What is a lexical scope?**

The scope defined in order in which code is authored. Lets say your class structure is as follows

```
OuterMost  
   --Inner  
     --InnerMost
```

Then the inner most class will be able to access variables from inner as well outer most.