# Some trouble with inner class visibility

Tags: java, subclass, inner-classes

I'm facing java inner class and I'm having some trouble with outer variables visibility.

```
class A {
    private int x = 5;
    class B extends A{
        public void fun(B b){
            b.x = 10; //here
        }
    }
}
```

Why I can't do something like this (see the "here" tag) if there are no visibility restrictions between inner and outer class? I'm really not understanding these rules.

Comment: `private` variables can be only modified in the class itself, not from the subclasses.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [outer class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578820/accessing-outer-class-variable-in-inner-class/17578924)

Answer (score 2):

In your example the member variable `x` is not a property of class B so `b.x = 10` makes no sesne, hence the error, it's nothing to do with visibility rules. Trying `x = 10` works fine, which is a short-cut for `A.this.x = 10` or `super.x = 10`.

Comment: *"the member variable `x` is not a property of class `B`"*: however true that is, I believe the question is really about what is the difference between `A.this.x = 10;` and `b.x = 10;`. After all, both are `B` instances (or is this where the confusion is)?

Comment: You need to update `b` instance, not `this`, you can do it by casting the instance to unsure visibility (since we are in an inner-class). `((A)b).x = 10;`

Answer (score 1):

Modifier `private` cannot be accessed in sub classes.

```
class A {
    private int x = 5; // The issue is in `private` in this line
    class B extends A{
        public void fun(B b){
            b.x = 10; //here
        }
    }
}
```

If you remove the modifier `private` and change it to `default`, `public` OR `protected`, you will be able to access the variable.

Please go through the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/) for better understanding.

**UPDATE:**

Remove **extends** keyword (Now Class B will not be a sub class but only an inner class), and the variable x will only be accessed using **this**  OR **super** keyword. The usage is elaborated at [link](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/nested-inner-class)

Comment: It's an inner class not a sub-class.

Comment: @stridecolossus it's both.

Comment: Updated the answer @stridecolossus

Comment: But they are accessible to an inner-class !

Answer (score 0):

you need know this three `private`，`protected`,`default`,`public`access specifiers

1. `private` variables only can be modified in the itself class.not include `subclass`
2. `default` variables can be modified in same package.
3. `protected` variables can be modified in subclass and in same package and itself
4. `public` variables can be modified any where.

> you can saw this on this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/)

beside.if you use this example ,this can modified your variables with using`super`specifiers to access your visiable

```
class A {
    private int x = 5;
    class B extends A{
        public void fun(B b){
            b.x = 10; //here error
            super.x=1;//this is ok
        }
    }
}
```

this `b.x = 10; //here error` this problem is b is a parm of a methods not a member-variable or a super class variable.

Comment: Both line are not doing the same thing. The first one update `b`, the second update `this`...

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite special. Inner class can access the private field of the outerclass. This can be shown with the `fun(A)` method

```
class A {
    private int x = 5;
    class B extends A{

        public void fun(A a){
            a.x = 5; //Valid since we are in the same class (inner-class can access private field)
        }
}
```

Now, if you have a `B` parameter, this is a bit different because it will try to use the inheritence instead of the outer-inner link :

```
public void fun(B b){
    b.x = 10; //Access using inheritence, not OK for private field
    ((A)b).x = 10; //Casting into A to be able to access the private field (just like fun(A).
}
```

Note that this is a problem because you update a reference receive in parameter, you can update the current inner instance easily

```
public void fun(){
    x = 10; //OK : access to A.x from inner class
    super.x = 10; //OK : same

    this.x = 10; // KO : trying to access a private variable from B scope
}
```

Comment: Yes but `x = 10` modifies A variable x, while `super.x = 10` modifies B variable x inherited from A, right?

Comment: No, `x = 10` is the same as `super.x = 10` here. `x` only exist in `A` so there is no variable `x` in `B`.